# Returning a value from a function, based on condition, one return statement vs. many return statements

Tags: php, coding-style, return

Suppose we want to return a value from a function based on a condition. We can do it in two ways:

```
function foo($bar) {
    if ($bar == 'value1') {
        return 'baz';
    }
    else if ($bar == 'value2') {
        return 'qux';
    }
}

function foo($bar) {
    $result = '';

    if ($bar == 'value1') {
        $result = 'baz';
    }
    else if ($bar == 'value2') {
        $result = 'qux';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I personally prefer the second approach.
Which way do you thing is better (specially considering longer if/else structures)?
Thanks.

Comment: No way is *better*. I'd prefer the first example as it's clear enough and avoids the `$result` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I like the second way, because it's more readable and you will not miss a return statement anywhere, especially if you have complicated if/else structures.

Answer (score 1):

I find this even more readable / clean / maintainable, but it may just be a matter of personal perference:

```
function foo($bar)
{
  if ($bar == 'value1')
    return 'baz';

  if ($bar == 'value2')
    return 'qux';
}
```

You can do as well, if $bar / return correspondencies are always "one to one":

```
function foo($bar)
{
  $ar_matches = array(
      'value1' => 'baz',
      'value2' => 'qux'
    );

  if (isset($ar_matches[$bar])
    return $ar_matches[$bar];
}
```